# Sorting on 4th element and keep the same key value in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have multiple array structure as below

```
array (
  'Mexico' => 
  array (
    'Regular_Club' => 
    array (
      '2015-02' => 
      array (
        'cost' => 41479.8,
        'signups' => 3891,
        'share' => 16241.46,
      ),
    ),
    'Sweepstakes' => 
    array (
      '2015-02' => 
      array (
        'cost' => 1186736.04,
        'signups' => 280850,
        'share' => 468069.14,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I want to sort this array descending order based on the field cost. I tried uasort, multisort but no luck. Result should be below.

```
Result: 
array (
  'Mexico' => 
  array (
   'Sweepstakes' => 
    array (
      '2015-02' => 
      array (
        'cost' => 1186736.04,
        'signups' => 280850,
        'share' => 468069.14,
      ),
    ),
    'Regular_Club' => 
    array (
      '2015-02' => 
      array (
        'cost' => 41479.8,
        'signups' => 3891,
        'share' => 16241.46,
      ),
    ),

  ),
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2015-02 is not fixed value it will change according to month so can't use that name and even the name regular_club or Sweepstakes they are not fixed name. It will change for other month, other countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coolect costs before and use uksort:

```
foreach ($inputArray as $country => $array) {
  foreach( $array as $key => $value)
    foreach ($value as $val) $weight[$key] = (int) $val['cost'];
       uksort($array, function ($k1, $k2) use ($weight) { return $weight[$k2] - $weight[$k1]; });    
  $resultArray = array($country => $array);
} 

var_export($resultArray);
```

Comment: In the result array Mexico also not fixed name. we will have different countries so I can not collect cost using fixed name. just take maxico as country key. It can be different country also.

Comment: Its not working. its not sorting on cost ... here in example I have written only 2 elements but originally i have many ... and its not sorting accordingly. its sorting only last two elements. Other objects were not sorted.

Comment: If you check https://eval.in/370435 . I am getting the same result. its not sorting descending.

Comment: @user1648204 my bad. try now

Comment: it works perfectly for last country array. Pleases check https://eval.in/371765 output array contains only India data. And other countries are missing.

Comment: change witn $resultArray[$country] = $array;